# Unable to publish https endpoint with WSO2 API Manager 1.7

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to publish a 'Production Endpoint' on the 'Implementation' screen. When I click the 'Test' button, I get 'Invalid' message. I've followed the documentation here:

https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Creating+an+API

I've been working with the axis2.xml file, replacing the default parameter name="HostnameVerifier" with "AllowAll" (per documentation), but I still get the same 'Invalid' message. I noticed there are several "transportSender" tags related to https config. I have a feeling I'm just not getting the right combination of params / values. Can someone post a complete axis2.xml file that enables https production endpoints?

Comment: I just solved this. The problem is that the server for which I created the endpoint (the "production endpoint") has an invalid certificate. I could not see the SSL cert warning when accessing via API Manager. But when I put the URL in my browser address bar, I get the SSL warning, indicating the server has an invalid certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the server for which I created the endpoint (the "production endpoint") has an invalid certificate. I could not see the SSL cert warning when accessing via API Manager. But when I put the URL in my browser address bar, I get the SSL warning, indicating the server has an invalid certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to see ssl handshaking related stuff in wso2 product .you can start the server using following command this will print all ssl handshake details.So you can check the certificate related details there.

```
 sh wso2server.sh -Djavax.net.debug=all
```